# Not getting azure oauth token when I am calling post from my api in JAVA

Tags: azure, spring-boot, oauth

I am calling my login api

```
localhost:9090/user/login?username=xyzxyz&password=xyzxyz (POST MAPPING)
```

it automatically call

```
GET http://localhost:9090/oauth2/authorization/azure


GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=9f7148a8f1-909ab498ddc8&scope=openid%20https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read&state=oQHpLT8bPXE4OCmAkBPQDwVD0v1ctcsV80R39V3FAFc%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9090/login/oauth2/code/azure&nonce=-W6vcvoim2iv01EvJbFPXFwF58VIF1LzcSDCiIlcGHs
```

### and I am getting no response.

How can I call

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/51d82e712c0cb/oauth2/v2.0/token

api from my login api (localhost:8090/user/login?username=xyzxyz&password=xyzxyz.

Please help

Comment: Is that you provide a login page to let user enter Azure AD userName and password then you want to get AD token with them?

Comment: yes.. it is automatically calling extra 2 api...

Comment: If so, you can use Azure AD ROPC flow : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc. But, please note that if you use the flow, the account cannot enable MFA.